# Any way to sort the Rows Fetch in SQL Using matching Criteria

Tags: mysql, sql

Im a bit new in SQL. What im trying to do is to sort the row in descending order of matching criteria. 
When I say matching criteria i mean the those rows that have more matching columns with my SQL Query should come first. Like

```
SELECT a.*, 
       f.* 
FROM   a  
       INNER JOIN f as f
               ON f.fid = a.aid 
WHERE  ( a.icid = 25290 
         AND a.pt = 2 ) 
       AND ( f.st LIKE '%Outpatient%' 
              OR f.st LIKE '%Service201%' )
```

Now the order of my rows should be that if it matches all it should come on the top, then on second should be the one that have matches all the columns but F.ST , then so on so forth.

example

i have 5 columns in a table name Test
the name of columns are

id, name, fname, city, country

My Query

```
SELECT * 
FROM TEST 
WHERE name LIKE "%John%" 
   OR fname LIKE "%Mike%" 
   OR city IN ("Abu Dhabi, New York, Manchester")
   OR country IN ("USA, UAE, UK")
```

Say that i have 10 rows against this query. 
What i want is that the row that matches all should come in top of result set
like following

name, fname, city, counrty

John, Mike,  New York, USA  -> matches all four fields

John, Mike,  Delhi, UK -> matches three fields

John, Khan,  Lahore, USA -> matches two fields

John, Khan,  Lahore, PK -> matches one field

John Mike, Khan,  Lahore, PK -> matches one field

Comment: maybe if you would add example data and expected result it would be more clear and you would get more answers

Comment: You have to use sql `IF()` if you want to orderby `like matches`

Comment: break your query and use union all

Comment: Can i have an example code please how to do it.

Comment: @GuidoG i have added some example code. What you make out of it? Who can i achieve what i want to do.

Answer (score 2):

MySQL will treat boolean expressions as integers, in a numeric context.  This makes your question easy to answer:

```
SELECT a.*, f.* 
FROM a INNER JOIN
     f f
     ON f.fid = a.aid 
WHERE a.icid = 25290 AND
      a.pt = 2 AND
      ( f.st LIKE '%Outpatient%' OR f.st LIKE '%Service201%' ) 
ORDER BY ( (f.st LIKE '%Outpatient%') + (f.st LIKE '%Service201%') ) DESC;
```

Note:  You can put the same expression in the `SELECT`, if you like:

```
SELECT . . .,
       ( (f.st LIKE '%Outpatient%') + (f.st LIKE '%Service201%')
       ) as numMatches
. . .
```

Comment: good idea to make use of type conversion that way (+1 for that). Small note: If one of the expressions return `NULL`, then the overall `numMatches` will be `NULL`, too. This is probably not intended, although it does not matter here, because it's always `f.st` that is addressed.

Comment: @StephanLechner . . . In order for the boolean expressions to return `NULL`, `f.st` would have to be `NULL` . . . and the `WHERE` clause would filter out such rows.

Answer (score 0):

Let me answer your question based on your second statement; you can then apply this strategy to other cases.
Assume that you want to weight several criteria; Then you could - for each criteria - use an `if`-statement that returns `0` if it is not fulfilled and "some weight" if it is fulfilled. Add these weights per criteria in a subquery and "order by" this weight in the outer query:

```
Select name, fname, city, country
from 
  (SELECT *, (if(name LIKE "%John%"),8,0)
           + if(fname LIKE "%Mike%", 4,0)  
           + if(city IN ("Abu Dhabi, New York, Manchester"), 2,0)  
           + if(country IN ("USA, UAE, UK"), 1,0) ) as weight
   FROM TEST)  weightedTest
where weight > 0
order by weight desc
```

Of course you can adapt the weights according to your demand; If you simply want to count how many criteria are fulfilled, you can assign a weight of 1 to each of the criteria.